# Finding the proper transaction gas and gasLimit combinations in contract deployment on private network

Tags: go-ethereum, ganache, gas-limit

### The long story

I am trying to deploy a contract to a private network. The contract is written in Solidity and pre-compiled into bytecode using Hardhat, and I've successfully tested it using Ganache with a gas limit of 6721975 and 6000000 gas provision in `sendTransaction` (the stupid contract takes a little bit over 4M gas to deploy). However, when I try to deploy the same contract onto a new network with Geth nodes, I struggle to find the proper settings for these numbers. (The same setup just don't seem to work, reporting **`exceeds block gas limit`** - and I don't know why.)

I manage to make things work by setting gas limit way high (over 2 billion) and using an account with a lot of wei by following these steps:

1. Initialize with a `genesis.json` like this:

   ```
   {
     "config": {
       "chainId": 10,
       "homesteadBlock": 0,
       "eip150Block": 0,
       "eip155Block": 0,
       "eip158Block": 0
     },
     "coinbase": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
     "difficulty": "0x0200000",
     "extraData": "",
     "gasLimit": "0x80000000",
     "mixhash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
     "parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
     "timestamp": "0x0",
     "nonce": "0x42",
     "alloc": {},
   }
   ```
2. Start the node with a miner account, and wait for it to mine some blocks
3. Create a new account for deployment
4. Transfer 1e19 wei to this new account (`gasPrice` is 1e9, much lower than Ganache)
5. Deploy the new contract in Web3.py with `gas = 6000000` (same as above)
6. And I can see the contract address returned, although I notice something weird: the gas consumption is significantly higher than what Ganache and Hardhat have reported (close to 5M, but still less than 6M)

Above is pretty much all I do to customize the node after a fresh install of Geth (and I don't think the start command will do any bad). And I can easily run into problems by tweaking the settings:

- If I only have 5e18 wei (half of above) in my account, it reports **`insufficient funds for gas * price + value`**. However, even this should be way more than enough.
- If I lower the gas limit to something like 10M, it reports `exceeds block gas limit` as aforementioned. (Why?)
- If I am providing more gas (like 9M, with a much higher gas limit) it reports `insufficient funds for gas * price + value` again.

I am hoping for nothing but to make it work, so I don't care what the values are. With that said, I still want to know something about what's happening behind the scene.

### The questions

1. Why are these gas errors reported on my Geth when the balance is more than enough and the gas limit does not seem to be exceeded? (Ganache works fine, though, and it's super convenient for me)
2. Are there any best practices for setting the `gasLimit` and gas provided in `sendTransaction` when using a private chain?

Comment: What geth version are you using? What are the geth command line parameters? What's the solc version used? The genesis  seems to be missing some of the new forks, did you try using puppeth to generate a genesis file? Newer solc version default to more recent EVM versions, if your geth is old or forks aren't enabled in the genesis contracts compiled with recent solc version might fail to deploy or execute. Also geth unless configured with the parameters will decrease the block gas limit to current values used in mainnet.

Comment: @Ismael Geth version 1.10.15 and solc version 0.8.4. As you mentioned, the genesis is missing several new forks which I discovered through puppeth but not provided by some tutorials. Adding them to the genesis fixed the issue as well as another issue that was consuming all the gas in contract call. Now the node seems to be working just fine. Thanks!